# Importing big database to PostgreSQL from R via RPostgreSQL library

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I need import a 10.352.223 KB data base in PostgresSQL. I am trying to do it via RPostgreSQL library in R, but I have had problems.

My code is:

```
i<-10000

for(a in seq(0,36000000, i)){
  data<-read.table("data.txt",sep="|",dec=",",
                     nrows=i,skip=a,fill=T,
                     colClasses=c(rep("NULL",2),"character",rep("NULL",64),
                                  rep("character",2),rep("NULL",11),
                                  "numeric",rep("NULL",9),"numeric",
                                  rep("NULL",2)))
  colnames(data)<-names
  data$iteration<-rep(a,dim(data)[1])
  dbWriteTable(con,"data",data, append=TRUE )
  print(paste("registry", a, sep = " "))
}
```

I have no problem until registry 469000, but in some moment I have this error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, :
could not allocate memory (2048 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'
```

I can't understand what's the problem if I am skipping a lot of rows and reading some specific rows.

What can I do? I must use PosgreSQL codes directly? There exist a better method in R?

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `psql` for this if you can. It has bulk insert facilities which the [RPostgreSQL](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgreSQL) package maybe lacking.

You can still use the package to execute commands to create the table etc pp.

You can of course *also* use the package to first insert the some N rows, and then append N more rows until you reach the total number of rows.